# Erro codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Bom, na INTRANET em desenvolvimento da empresa, fiz uma parte de memorando e osti simples, mas ambos não estão funcionando. São quase iguais, segue código:

**TELA**

```
// Tela de envio de OSTI
            case 'enviar_osti':
                $CI =& get_instance();
                echo '<ol class="breadcrumb caminho">'.breadcrumb().'</ol>';
                echo form_open(current_url(), array('class'=>'form-padrao'));
                erros_validacao();
                get_msg('msgok');
                get_msg('msgerro');
                echo '<h4><img src="gl/glyphicons-87-display.png"> Ordem de Solicitação de TI</h4>';
                echo '<hr>';
                echo '<div class="form-group">';
                echo form_label('Título do problema:');
                echo form_input(array('name'=>'titulo', 'class'=>'form-control campo6', 'placeholder'=>'Digite o assunto da solicitação'), set_value('titulo'), 'autofocus');
                echo '</div>';  
                echo '<div class="form-group">';
                echo form_label('<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Descrição do problema:'); echo '<i> [máx. de 520 caracteres]</i>';
                echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'des', 'class'=>'form-control campo6', 'placeholder'=>'Digite os detalhes da solicitação'), set_value('des'));
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="form-group">';
                echo form_label('E-mail do solicitante:');
                echo form_input(array('name'=>'email', 'class'=>'form-control campo6', 'disabled'=>'disabled'), set_value('email', $CI->session->userdata('user_email')));
                echo '</div>';       
                echo '<hr>';
                echo anchor('home','<i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Voltar',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-padrao'));          
                ?><button name="enviar_osti" class="btn btn-success btn-padrao" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Enviar</button><?php            
            echo form_close();      
            break;
```

**FUNÇÃO**

```
//====================  Envio de OSTI

    public function enviar_osti(){
        $CI =& get_instance();

        if (esta_logado()):
                $this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', 'O tamanho para o %s foi excedido!');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('titulo','TITULO','required|ucwords');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('des','DESCRIÇÃO','required|max_length[520]');
                $email = $CI->session->userdata('user_email');
                if($this->form_validation->run()==TRUE):
                    $titulo = $this->input->post('titulo');
                    $des = $this->input->post('des');
                    if ($this->sistema->enviar_email_osti($email, $titulo, $des)):
                        set_msg('msgok','OSTI enviada com sucesso!','sucesso');
                        redirect('servicos/enviar_osti');
                    else:
                        set_msg('msgerro','Erro ao enviar OSTI, contate o administrador','erro');
                        redirect('servicos/enviar_osti');
                    endif;

                endif;
                set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('telas','enviar_osti'));
                load_template();

        else:
            load_template();
```

endif;
    }

```
//função de enviar email ao gerar OSTI
    public function enviar_email_osti($solicitante, $titulo, $mensagem, $formato='html'){
        $this->CI->load->library('email');
        $config['mailtype'] = $formato;
        $this->CI->email->initialize($config);
        $this->CI->email->from($solicitante);
        $this->CI->email->to('spiceworks@coppersteel.com.br');
        $this->CI->email->subject($titulo);
        $this->CI->email->message($mensagem);
        if ($this->CI->email->send()):
            return TRUE;
        else:
            return $this->CI->email->print_debugger();
        endif;

    }
```

Poderiam me ajudar..

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro? talvez o `&` seja o problema.

Comment: então na verdade ele não retorna erro, ele faz certo, da a mensagem que foi salvo, mas não é enviado no email.... nossa parte de requisição de compra agora também,  ela salva no banco de dado, retorna mensagem de sucesso mas a parte de email não vai!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, dá uma olhada pois dependendo das configurações de SMPT do servidor, não vai mesmo.. Tive o mesmo problema, consegui corrigir usando o phpMailer com SMTP.